# Passing empty string to argparse

Tags: python, command-line, argparse, python-3.2

I'm using `argparse` (Python 3.2). A parameter `mode` is defined simply as:

```
p.add_argument('--mode', dest='mode')
```

I want to call the program from the command line in such a way that parameter `mode` is set to an empty string; or at least to a single space `' '` (I can strip whitespace later).

I tried to use (under Windows) `program_name --mode ""` and `program_name --mode " "`, but neither worked.

Comment: What happens if you try `--mode=` ?

Comment: Why not just omit it and use a default value?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think it tried to omit the parameter, which is my global argument_default.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to work for me under OS-X:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--mode')
p = parser.parse_args()
print(p)
```

and then:

```
python test.py --mode=
```

I don't have a windows machine, so I don't know anything about how those operate...

Of course, the other things you mentioned above would work as well on OS-X.  The advantage here is that it shouldn't rely on how the shell splits arguments enclosed in quotations which should make it work in more places I would think.